# applying clear-fix or micro clear-fix with just jquery

Tags: jquery, css-float, clearfix

so what I'm trying to do is apply either of the clear-fix or micro clear-fix with jquery.  The reason is I don't have access to the CSS so I've been using jquery to make all of my classes and other css related needs.  This is really the one thing I haven't been able to do so I need some help.

both methods:
clearfix

```
.clearfix:after {
content: ".";
display: block;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
line-height: 0;
height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
display: inline-block;
}
```

and micro clearfix

```
.cf:before, .cf:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.cf:after { clear: both; }
.cf { zoom: 1; }
```

use psuedo techniques and I'm not sure how to apply this with jquery.  I have been doing

```
var small_h = {
    "font-size":    "10.4px",
    "margin-left":  "7px"  
};

$(".small_h").css(small_h);
```

for my css traditionally, but because I don't have access to teh style sheets I need to define these using Jquery only.  Certainly doesn't have to be like that if you can think of a clever way to do this,  strange request I know, but it's a work restriction,  thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `$(".small_h").css(small_h).addClass('cf');`

Comment: well so the problem is I can't actually add any of taht stuff to the css, so I'm trying to define those classes using the jquery.

Answer (score 0):

To inject CSS into the page, use:

```
var css = '.clearfix:after ......... ';
$('<style type="text/css">' + css + '</style>').appendTo('head');
```

Then, to apply the class:

```
$(".small_h").css(small_h).addClass('cf');
```

Comment: I tried this and for some reason the content management system turns style into div and breaks it, so that's why I had been doing everything like this var small_h = {
    "font-size":    "10.4px",
    "margin-left":  "7px"  
};

$(".small_h").css(small_h);

Comment: _"the content management system turns style into div and breaks it"_ >> This means that your CMS is either modifying jQuery itself or the browser-level DOM methods.  This jQuery code is only calling DOM methods to add a `<style>` block.

Comment: so is there a way to apply the clearfix with the jquery using the method I had been using instead?  Cause that's been working consistently.

Comment: Instead of using a CSS fix, use an element fix: `$(".small_h").css(small_h).after('<br style="clear:both;"/>');`

Answer (score 0):

You could append a style block directly into to head.

For example:

```
$('head').append('<style type="text/css"> .c{ color:red; } .c:after{ content:\' :)\'; } </style>');​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xgYYP/

Comment: I tried this and for some reason the content management system turns style into div and breaks it, so that's why I had been doing everything like this var small_h = {
    "font-size":    "10.4px",
    "margin-left":  "7px"  
};

$(".small_h").css(small_h);

Comment: @loriensleafs that's really strange. have you tried appending it to the body maybe?

Comment: I don't think it's the append that's not working, it's that the word style gets changed to div.  Any way to add it using the method I had been using or a different method?